# How to create customized mime types using MediaType class in jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

How can I create customized mime types using MediaType class in jersey?
Below is my code:

```
public class MimeTypeClass extends MediaType {

    public static final String APPLICATION_IMAGE_JPEG = "image/jpeg";
}
```

While I'm building body part I'm getting a compilation error:

```
FormDataBodyPart bodyPart1 = new FormDataBodyPart(
FormDataContentDisposition.name("Thumbnail").fileName("thumbnail").build(), 
inputStreamThumbNail, MimeTypeClass.APPLICATION_IMAGE_JPEG);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a String, not a MediaType. A wrapper for custom media-types could look like this:

```
public class CustomMediaTypes {

    public final static String IMAGE_JPEG = "image/jpeg";

    public final static MediaType IMAGE_JPEG_TYPE = new MediaType("image", "jpeg");

}
```

Then you would pass `CustomMediaTypes.IMAGE_JPEG_TYPE` to the `FormDataBodyPart` constructor and `CustomMediaTypes.IMAGE_JPEG` for instance to a `@Consumes` annotation